# IE jumps to Google Maps iframe position after page load

Tags: google-maps, internet-explorer, iframe

I have an embedded Google Maps iframe on a single page site. The iframe is located almost at the bottom of the page and works well on all browsers except IE.

Whenever the page is loaded in IE, it suddenly jumps down the view to the iframe position.

I have no JS written to do such behaviour and I have actually tried to remove all JS in order to isolate the issue, but it still happens.

I also tried to put a small function on my document.ready() and window.load() functions to scroll to top as a last resource but no luck.

Has anyone seen this issue or know of a workaround?

This is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="http://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/embed?mid=zjeRyuQhhp6E.kQ_jGdVVM3y0&z=17" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

And you can see it live [here](http://oceanaresidences.mx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact issue.  The only solution I was able to find was to use a this [plugin](http://ressio.github.io/lazy-load-xt/demo/widget-iframe.htm). Hope this helps.